# Next image in scrollview overlaps the new view when pushing?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview that displays a bunch of images. When choosing the current image in the scrollview, it will push to a new view (using a navigation controller).

My problem is when I push, I see the next imageview of the scrollview overlaps the new view before it dismisses (like ghost). I know that's because of: "scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO". But I want to set this attribute to NO because I wanna see a part of last image and next image in the scrollview. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible way(kind of trick) to overcome this would be to hide the scrollView controller just before pushing the new view and when you come back to this view show the scrollview again using:

```
scrollView.hidden  = NO;
```